# tkinter Listbox unchecks and calls binded function entries when tab pressed

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

So I am trying to create multiple listboxes in one window with python tkinter. I defined the listBoxes like:

```py
def create_list_box(self, text, row_nr):
    tk.Label(self.inner_frame, text=text).grid(column=0, row=row_nr, sticky=tk.W)
    box = tk.Listbox(self.inner_frame, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE)
    box.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", lambda e: on_change(e))

    for i in range(len(cats)): 
        box.insert(i, cats[i])

    box.grid(column=1, row=row_nr)

create_list_box("Some text", 1)
create_list_box("Some text", 2)
```

With the `on_change` function like:

```py
def on_change(event):
    # Do something here
```

With this setup I ran into two problems which are probably related:

1. If I press `<Tab>`, the on_change is called as well.
2. If the `<Tab>` is pressed, the selection in the Listbox would disappear.

I tried to resolve issue 1 by adding:

```py
def on_change(event):
    print(event.keysym) # For debugging
    if event.keysym == '<Tab>':
        return

    # Do something here
```

Now this solution would result in the output `??` every time I press enter or when I click a listbox item (Also for keycode). As a second attempt I tried to bind the tab key in order to let it do something else with adding this line to `create_list_box`:

```py
    box.bind("<Tab>", do_nothing_function)
```

However this would not have any effect. Lastly I tried to save the input in the `on_change` function and select all the input again with the listbox.selection_set() function with the code:

```py
def on_change(self, event, row_nr):
    listBox = self.gui.inner_frame.grid_slaves(row=row_nr, column=1)[0]
    actives = [listBox.get(idx) for idx in listBox.curselection()]

    if np.array_equal(actives, self.saved_actives[row_nr]): 
        return
        
    elif self.saved_actives[i] and not actives: 
        indexes = [self.listbox_options.index(a) for a in self.saved_actives[i]]
        for index in indexes: listBox.selection_set(index)
    else: 
        self.active_cats[i] = actives
        
        # Do something here
```

Where `self.active_cats` is a `dictionary` as the selected items can be different for the different listboxes. In the `create_list_box` function, the `box.bind` line is adjusted to:

```py
    box.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", lambda e, r=row_nr: self.on_change(e, r)
```

This would work as long as there is only 1 Listbox. When there are more, this would get stuck in an endless loop as soon as any item in the second list is selected.

Does anyone have any  more ideas?

Comment: You can set `exportselection=0` when creating the instance of `Listbox()`.